# using python stream downloading file with server limit

Tags: python, web-crawler, python-requests

I tried to download file from a server using python, sometimes the file is very large, I would like to have some progress bar, one way to do this I can come up with is to download in a stream, so that I can print the progress. Currently I have tried the standard urlopen, urlretrieve, and requests module (with stream on).

Obviously, urlopen cannot download file in stream, requests module support this, however, the server has limit on the file I can download at one time (its limit is 1). So everytime, I tried to use requests, it only get the webpage told me to wait, is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have very recently downloaded many types of media with this function:

```
import sys
import requests
import time
def download_resource(domain, url, file_name = None, download = True):
    cookies = {}
    s = requests.Session()

    s.config['keep_alive'] = True
    #add your own cookies here, I have a specific function I call
    #for my application but yours is different
    r = s.get(url, cookies = cookies, stream = True)

    if not r.ok:
        print "error in downloading"
        return -1

    file_size = int(r.headers['content-length']) 

    if not file_name:
        try:
            temp = r.headers['content-disposition']
        except Exception as e:
            pass
            #failing download
            return -1
        else:
            if not temp:
                return -1
            else:
                file_name = temp.split("filename=")[-1]
                return_obj["filename"] = file_name
    #print "File size:", file_size
    #print "\n", str(self.entire_size / float(1024*1024*1024)), "\n"
    print "Downloading:", file_name
    if download:
        with open(file_name, "wb") as fh:
            count = 1
            chunk_size = 1048576
            start_time = time.time()
            try:
                for block in r.iter_content(chunk_size):
                    total_time = time.time() - start_time
                    percent = count*chunk_size/float(file_size) * 100.0
                    fraction = int(percent/5)

                    download_speed = 1.0 / total_time

                    sys.stdout.write('\r')
                    sys.stdout.write("[%-20s] %d%%  %3.2f MB/s       " % ('='* fraction , percent, download_speed))
                    sys.stdout.flush()
                    if not block:
                        break
                    fh.write(block)
                    count += 1
                    start_time = time.time()
            except Exception as e:
                print e
            finally:    
                #close up the stream
                r.close()
```

Comment: I did similar thing, but only received a webpage saying I need to wait several seconds before downloading the next file, and after several seconds, it said the same thing again. I guess this is because the server limit one connection at same time. If I make stream=False, this won't happen. Any idea?

Comment: are you using a session object in requests? From what I understand you are saying is that the webserver limits number of concurrent connections from a single client to one. If you are not using a session object I would try that, and set keep-alive.

Comment: I did use session, but I turned off keep-alive and forget to turn it on. I am going to try it again. Thanks!

Comment: works now, but still have a problem, see [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30056960/why-python-print-is-delayed)