# Why python print is delayed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler, python-requests

I am trying to download file using requests, and print a dot every time retrieve 100k size of file, but all the dots is printed out at the end. See code.

```
with open(file_name,'wb') as file:
    print("begin downloading, please wait...")
    respond_file = requests.get(file_url,stream=True)
    size = len(respond_file.content)//1000000

    #the next line will not be printed until file is downloaded
    print("the file size is "+ str(size) +"MB")
    for chunk in respond_file.iter_content(102400):
        file.write(chunk)
        #print('',end='.')
        sys.stdout.write('.')
        sys.stdout.flush()
    print("")
```

Comment: What parts are delayed? Some of the  `print()` calls or the `sys.stdout.write()` calls as well?

Comment: Wild guess: accessing `respond_file.content` forces the request to complete in its entirety before it can proceed to the next line. Try deleting the `size = ...` and `print("the file size is...` lines, and see if your dots get printed in a more timely manner.

Comment: @Kevin: I missed that, but the guess is correct.

Comment: Yes, it is .content makes the printing dot delayed, it can be solved according to the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are accessing `request.content` here:

```
size = len(respond_file.content)//1000000
```

Accessing that property forces the whole response to be downloaded, and for large responses this takes some time. Use `int(respond_file.headers['content-length'])` instead:

```
size = int(respond_file.headers['content-length']) // 1000000
```

The `Content-Length` header is provided by the server and since it is part of the headers you have access to that information without downloading all of the content first.

If the server chooses to use `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` to stream the response, no `Content-Length` header has to be set; you may need to take that into account:

```
content_length = respond_file.headers.get('content-length', None)
size_in_kb = '{}KB'.format(int(content_length) // 1024) if content_length else 'Unknown'
print("the file size is", size_in_kb)
```

where the size in kilobytes is calculated by dividing the length by 1024, not 1 million.

Alternatively, ask for the size in a separate HEAD request (only fetching the headers):

```
head_response = requests.get(file_url)
size = int(head_response.headers.get('content-length', 0))
```

Comment: Thanks all, but when I try to get content-length from headers, I got the following error: keyerror, and I printed the response header: {'server': 'nginx/1.4.2', 'date': 'Tue, 05 May 2015 16:18:44 GMT', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'content-type': 'text/html', 'connection': 'close'}, is there anyway to solve it?

Comment: @1a1a11a: then the server is not giving you a length up front, and you'll not be able to give a message about the size. Will update.

Comment: is there any other way to know the size of the file before downloading?

Comment: @1a1a11a: you could use a `HEAD` request on the URL perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

This should work how you expect. Getting the length of respond_file is not what you wanted. Instead check the content-length header.

Note: I changed the code to display KB instead (for the purposes of testing).

```
import requests
import sys

file_url = "https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/archive/master.zip"
file_name = "out.zip"

with open(file_name,'wb') as file:
    print("begin downloading, please wait...")
    respond_file = requests.get(file_url,stream=True)
    size = int(respond_file.headers['content-length'])//1024

    #the next line will not be printed until file is downloaded
    print("the file size is "+ str(size) +"KB")
    for chunk in respond_file.iter_content(1024):
        file.write(chunk)
        #print('',end='.')
        sys.stdout.write('.')
        sys.stdout.flush()
    print("")
```

Comment: Thanks all, but when I try to get content-length from headers, I got the following error: keyerror, and I printed the response header: {'server': 'nginx/1.4.2', 'date': 'Tue, 05 May 2015 16:18:44 GMT', 'transfer-encoding': 'chunked', 'content-type': 'text/html', 'connection': 'close'}, is there anyway to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

As @kevin writes in a comment, `respond.file.content` blocks the execution until the whole content is downloaded. The only difference between my answer and his comment is that I'm not guessing ;)